# error: invalid type argument of '->' - Printing the address of a struct field that is also a struct

Tags: c, struct, printf

I have a struct like this:

```
struct my_struct {
    struct_a a;
    struct_b b;
};
```

I am trying to print the address of a variable of `my_struct` type and also the addresses of its fields, `a` and `b`, which are also structs:

```
void some_function(my_struct *my) {     
     //....
     printf("my addr: %p - a addr: %p - b addr: %p", my, (void *) &my->a,   
                (void *) &my->b);
}

int main() {        
     my_struct my; //my is initialized in a function...
     //then, it is passed to some_function(...) bellow...
     printf("my addr: %p - a addr: %p - b addr: %p", my, (void *) &my->a,   
                (void *) &my->b);
     some_function(&my);
     return 0;
}
```

I am getting the following error:

> error: invalid type argument of '->' (have 'struct my_struct')

What is wrong with my understanding?

Comment: `my` is not a pointer, so you access its elements with `.` rather than `->`.

Comment: @ChristianGibbons `my` is a pointer...

Comment: Oh, wait. There are two `my`s.

Comment: @EugeneSh. Ha, I didn't even notice the one passed in as an argument.  Yeah, that is confusing.

Comment: @ChristianGibbons I didn't notice the other one :) Means something about the cognitive differences..

Comment: Asides: a) I hope that `pritnf` is the only typo. b) you should also cast the first argument `my` as `(void *) my`

Comment: Sorry, guys... when I put the code, I caused some misunderstanding in it... `my` is initialized outside the `some_function()`; then, its passed when I call `some_function()`. I edited my question to clarify this.

Comment: @EugeneSh. I started at the bottom of the code and worked my way up.  Stopped when I found `my` declared.

Comment: @DaltonCézane Can you provide a [mcve]? I tweaked the code a bit to be able to compile it, but I can't repro: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/be082558cb10e356

Comment: You are right, @Holy . I updated my question, now, inserting a part of the `main` function that was the responsible for the error I was getting: using `->` instead of `.`. Thank you all of you that tried to help and sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Moral of the story: do not use the same variable name everywhere

Comment: And also provide MCVEs right away. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is actually in your `main` function where `my` is an instance of `struct my_struct`, so using the `->` operator on it is invalid.  Change the `printf` call to use `.` instead:

```
int main() {        
     my_struct my; //my is initialized in a function...
     //then, it is passed to some_function(...) bellow...
     printf("my addr: %p - a addr: %p - b addr: %p", (void *)&my, (void *) &my.a,   
                (void *) &my.b);
     some_function(&my);
     return 0;
}
```

Note also that `main` must return an `int`.

Comment: thank you for your answer. I had an error in my code: that local variable did not exist in `some_function()`. I edited my question, fixing this. But my code is like yours, except the (void *) my, and still giving errors in `&my->a` and `&my->b` parts...

Comment: @DaltonCézane The function as I have it compiles.  Are you sure you don't have `my` defined elsewhere in the function?

Comment: You are right. I will mark your answer as "the answer". Can you please just insert a piece of code when `my` is not used as a pointer? In this case, we have to use `&my.a` and `&my.b`...
This was my problem... I am debugging a code and I put a `printf` inside a function that receives `my_struct *my` and also I use this same `printf` inside the `main` function, in which `my` is declared... So, I had to change `->` to `.` in the main function.

Comment: This does not answer the **current version** of the question. Normally, the question had to be rolled back, as the lastest edit left the answer without context. But the problem is without the edit the question lacks a [mcve] and this answer does also not answer the previous version, but some very old version which should not even compile due to re-declarationm with different type. So I leave the question and ask you to edit the answer to match the current version. @DaltonCézane please do **not** edit your question if the edit leaves an answer without context! This is against site rules.

Comment: @too , I had edited the question putting the part that was missing: the `main` function. So, now it is clear what was the problem and, as the edit in the answer, also is clear what was the solution. My bad the first description of the problem. I typed it fast and did not take care with MCVE. As I said, I am sorry... but I fixed the question, adding the part that was missing and I am sure now it really does make sense.

Comment: @DaltonCézane: You completely changed the meaning of the question by changing the code of the function you already had posted. The only reason I don't roll back your edit is the question was premature. Nevertheless,  wonder why you accepted it, as it does **not** answer the question. Only such questions shall be accepted, simply because the accept tick is for future readers. As it is now, you are just confusing them. I'm currently reconsidering to rollback.

Comment: @dbush The edit should have removed the original part completely, as the code before would have resulted in a compiler diagnostic, i.e. not compile at all (the scope is the same for parameters and variables in the function's body).

Comment: @toohonestforthissite I had left the text of the original answer for historical context as that's what was present when the answer was accepted.  I've removed that part so as not to confuse future readers.

Comment: @dbush: Thanks. FYI: see this foonote http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#note164 (and the paragraph it contains) to see why the original code would have created a different message (which would have made the problem very obvious).

Comment: @too , as I explained: it was my mistake! I edited the question with the *real*  problem. If you read the question now, you will clearly understand the problem! And the answer @dbush put is the right answer for my described problem! I made a confusion in my code, changing `.` by `->` and I really think people with same error, when reading this answer will understand and fix his/her problem! Too many text/confusion because a question that is already clear and already has an answer. If you still disagree, please remove the question if you can. I tried, to avoid this kind of comments, but I cant.